# Why am I getting Pyinstaller FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

I am trying to create a standalone app from my Python script **login.py** although I am getting the error when running it:

I have changed the **login.spec** and added the datas list as at the official documentation [Using Spec Files](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html)

`/Users.../` is just the summarised path to make it readable here, it is complete in my file.

`datas=[ ('/Users.../tiktok/*.png', '.' ) , ('/Users/.../tiktok/*.jpg', '.' ) ],`

Command to create the bundle:

> `pyinstaller -D -F -w login.spec login.py`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "login.py", line 126, in <module>
  File "login.py", line 82, in main
  File "PIL/Image.py", line 2904, in open
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/liberty.jpg'
[53518] Failed to execute script login
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

That means that the `.jpg` and `.png` are not bundled.

**login.py**

```py
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import requests
import json

def main():
    global rootLogin
    rootLogin = Tk()

    rootLogin.geometry("720x540")
    rootLogin.eval('tk::PlaceWindow . center')
    rootLogin.title("Login | bla bla bla")

    # Logo
    load = Image.open(curPath + "/liberty.jpg")
    load = load.resize((136, 84), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)
    img = Label(rootLogin, image=render)
    img.image = render
    img.place(x=293, y=86)

    # Username
    ...
    # Password
    ...

    # Forgot password
    ...

    # Login
    ...

    rootLogin.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import os
    curPath = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    print(curPath)
    main()
```

**login.spec**

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None

a = Analysis(['login.py'],
             pathex=['/Users/.../tiktok'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[ ('/Users.../tiktok/*.png', '.' ) , ('/Users/.../tiktok/*.jpg', '.' ) ],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='login',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=False )
app = BUNDLE(exe,
             name='login.app',
             icon=None,
             bundle_identifier=None)
```

Comment: It is because `curPath` is empty string.

Comment: Nope... this is not the problem, it isn’t empty, it works when I run the .py file and it is assigned `curPath = os.path.dirname(__file__)`

Comment: If you use `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))`, then it is not empty.  Also after building the exe using PyInstaller, the path using `__file__` is not the actual path you want, it is `sys._MEIPASS`.  The error definitely tell you that `curPath` is empty.

Comment: I found the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674790/bundling-data-files-with-pyinstaller-onefile

Answer (score 3):

[DUPLICATED]

I found the answer here [Bundling data files with PyInstaller (--onefile)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674790/bundling-data-files-with-pyinstaller-onefile)

The problem is:
**pyinstaller unpacks data into a temporary folder**

Just include the function:

```py
def resourcePath(relativePath):
    """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
    try:
        # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in _MEIPASS
        basePath = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        basePath = os.path.abspath(".")

    return os.path.join(basePath, relativePath)
```

and reference it in: `load = Image.open(curPath + "/liberty.jpg")`

changed to: `load = Image.open(resourcePath("liberty.jpg"))`

```py
# Logo
load = Image.open(resourcePath("liberty.jpg"))
load = load.resize((136, 84), Image.ANTIALIAS)
render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)
img = Label(rootLogin, image=render)
img.image = render
img.place(x=293, y=86)
```

**Output**
*# in development*

```
>>> resourcePath("liberty.jpg")
"/Users/marcelo/.../tiktok/liberty.jpg"
```

**Output**
*# # in production*

```
>>> resourcePath("liberty.jpg")
"/var/folders/yg/z47pdjvx3jg1y2f_58xmpd3m0000gn/T/_MEI4qD8I6/liberty.jpg"
```